# Draw blocks around form elements and add headings using CSS pseudo elements

Tags: css, pseudo-element

I have the following html which is generated by a web framework so I can't change it. I can however add my own CSS.

```
<table border="0" class="formlayout" role="presentation">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">Medical Aid Plan</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">Adult Medical Aid Dependants</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
         <td align="right">Child Medical Aid Dependants</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">Total Package</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">Pensionable Earnings</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
         <td align="right">Pensionable Earnings Percentage</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td align="right">Voluntary Contributions</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
         <td align="right">Voluntary Contributions Percentage</td>
         <td align="left"><input type="text"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

I would like to create sections in the form and draw blocks around these sections , complete with text section headings. In order to achieve this I was thinking of adding additional space between the table rows and then adding CSS pseudo elements for the text and section frames. How would one do this?

I would like to add the first 3 text inputs to Section 1 and the rest to Section 2.

I'm trying to achieve something like this:
[image: Trying to achieve something like this]

Comment: You might need a visual aid of what you want and a jsfiddle would be good also

Comment: Pretty sure you wouldn't be able to hook a pseudo-element onto a specific item to provide the separation & styling you are looking for. Even positioning the pseudo-elements would be problematical when using a table. I'd be more inclined to re-think how to get the table (if you must use a table) into a more appropriate format. Perhaps multiple `tbody` elements you could style.

Comment: I can't change the table or html, only css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done. But it only works with a fixed width layout (unless you use mediaqueries) and I don't know about browser compatibility. 
It would be easier to set some padding and a background image.

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/L7y5rz9j/

```
table.formlayout {
  width: 730px;
}
table.formlayout td {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(1) td {
  padding-top: 1em;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(3) td {
  padding-top: 3em;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(1):after, table.formlayout tr:nth-child(3):after {
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 750px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(1):after {
  height: 5em;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(3):after {
  height: 6em;
  margin-top: 2em;
}
table.formlayout tr:first-child td:first-child:after, table.formlayout tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 3em;
  padding: 2px 5px;       
  margin-left: 7em;
  background: white;
}
table.formlayout tr:first-child td:first-child:after {
  content:"Step 1";
  top: -9px;
}
table.formlayout tr:nth-child(3) td:first-child:after {
  content:"Step 2";
  top: 23px;
}
```